# Django user specific folders

Tags: python, django, directory

I want to create user specific folders for files uploaded by users. This is my `views.py`:

```
@login_required
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('upload.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # An empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'upload/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

This is my `models.py`:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y.%m.%d')
```

My idea is this. Instead of naming it `uploads/%Y.%m.%d` I stick the username somewhere in there. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: pass the current user after the form.is_valid():
`user = request.user`
And pass it as an argument to your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something like that in my `models.py`:

```
def _upload_path(instance,filename):
    return instance.get_upload_path(filename)

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=_upload_path)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

    def get_upload_path(self,filename):
        return "static/uploads/"+str(self.user.id)+"/"+filename
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I must be doing something wrong. I get  " 'Document' object has no attribute 'user' "

Comment: This is because your Document model doesn't have a user field.

Comment: So I must first define the user object with an id?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough, this returns an error: " no such column: upload_document.user_id "

Comment: I don't know.. did you add the user to the instance? Something like that: newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'], user = request.user)

Comment: Same error :/ But thanks for the help. I'm closer to a solution because of your help!

Comment: Maybe is because you haven't update your database, and the user field doesn't exist in the object? (Remove and create de db again). Anyway, this site has great tools to be thankful ;)